# How can I know from the specs if a laptop will work well with Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, ssd, opensuse

If I have the specs, is there any way to know if I can install a Linux distribution (openSUSE, Ubuntu) and have all the important things work well?

SSD
BIOS/UEFI allow install from USB
trackpad
gpu/screen
wifi

etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know what hardware works well with linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/16520/how-to-know-what-hardware-works-well-with-linux)

Comment: 1) There's no "Linux". With ArchLinux, you'll get the latest drivers. With Debian, you won't. 2) There's no common definition of "work well". Support for certain functionality may be better or worse depending on the specific chip, e.g. 3D graphics, data throughput. => Get a live image of your favourite distro and go to the department store, ask whether you may boot it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to idenfify whether your hardware will work as expceted with software is to compare the device's specs against the recommended specification for the software you plan on installing.

You can find the minimum requirements for Ubuntu here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

and openSUSE here
https://en.opensuse.org/Hardware_requirements

Installing the distro from a flash drive will depend on the BIOS firmware you have. You *should* be alright as most firmare versions allow you to do this, but I'd do some research just to make sure.

Most of the time, Linux works 'out of the box' because of pre-installed drivers, but if you find some of your components aren't working properly, you may need to install additional drivers. A great guide has been given here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers

Comment: Thank you. What about a device that just came out and there's no results online of anyone installing Linux on it? The LG Gram 14 for example

Comment: The above still applies as you'll always be able to find the specification for your device somewhere :) I've just had a quick look and it looks like your device is more than adequate for running either distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm mostly worried about things like the trackpad or graphics not working, or not being able to get in to the BIOS to install from USB

Comment: No worries. If for some reason you need to install additional drivers (which I doubt), you'll be able to find them somewhere and it's not a terribly complicated procedure. Remember to hit that up arrow on my answer if I've helped you *smile*